# Как остановить исполнение кода при вызове модального окна в ASP.NET

Tags: ajax, asp.net

Создаю и запускаю модальное окно в ASP.NET с помощью `AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender`.

Как сделать, чтобы при вызове модального окна исполнение кода остановилось и продолжилось после закрытия окна?

Comment: никак, оно так не работает. Смиритесь с тем, что выполнение кода продолжается после появления "модального окна".

Comment: @Igor спасибо. А можете подсказать, есть ли какое-нибудь свойство, с помощью которого можно определить, что в данный момент модальное окно активно (запущено)?

Comment: может быть Вам подойдет вот это:  http://forums.asp.net/t/1591707.aspx (http://weblogs.asp.net/yousefjadallah/add-shown-amp-add-hiding-modalpopupextender-events)